# When and how should I follow up again on an interview? (6 weeks since interview)

Tags: interviewing

I interviewed for my dream position at the beginning of August (about 6 weeks ago) and I thought the interview went really well. It was made clear before the interview that this would just be an initial interview. During the interview, my interviewer stater that he'd love to bring me in for a second interview to the actual office (I live several states away from where the job will be) to meet others and see how I like it. A day after the interview, I sent a follow-up thank you email to my interviewer and he indicated that it was a pleasure to meet me and he looked forward to talking to me again soon.  I didn't hear anything for the rest of the month, so at the end of the month (about a month after my initial interview), I sent a follow-up e-mail, expressing my continued interest and asking if there had been a status update. My interviewer responded and said he was finishing interviewing other candidates that week and he looked forward to speaking with me again soon either that week or the following week.  It has now been 2 weeks since the interviewer's e-mail and I haven't heard anything.  This is my dream position and every day I am hoping to hear back.  I would even personally pay to fly out for a second interview.

My question is - at what point should I follow up again? Should I even follow up again?  By the way, this is for a public sector position and I know the hiring process can be longer for the public sector than the private sector.  This is an absolute dream position for me and I feel like it perfectly fits my interests and skillset. I could see myself staying at that job for many years. I would love to follow up again if it would help, but I don't want to bother the interviewer, who I am sure is very busy.  Any advice is much appreciated!

Edit: This question is not a duplicate because I am not the same person who asked the other question and that person hadn't heard for 1 week. In my case, I have followed up once (after the thank you letter) and it has now been 6 weeks since my interview. It's a different situation and what one would do to follow up after 1 week could very well differ from what one would do to follow up after 6 weeks.  I would appreciate any advice on how and when to follow up.

Comment: If you do decide to follow up, you should probably wait no more or less than another week or two.

Answer (score 2):

> When and how should I follow up again on an interview?

The sad fact is that most likely at this point you are out of the running for the position you applied for, and should continue your search.  If the company was interested they would have reached out to you already.  They have your contact information I am sure.

You *could* call or email them one last time to be sure, but I believe this opportunities ship has sailed.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you see the job as a perfect fit for you, I'd say it's certainly worth sending another follow up email - you've got nothing to lose. I was recently involved in a recruitment process, and despite best intentions, work and unforeseen issues can crop up which sets the whole process back. There could be any number of reasons for the delay.

"Touching base" is fine, as long as it's not every other day - which it isn't in your case - two weeks is fine. Just a casual non-impatient sounding email would suffice. Hopefully you'll get a positive response.

Comment: OP here.  This question is not a duplicate because I am not the same person who asked the other question and that person hadn't heard for 1 week. In my case, I have followed up once (after the thank you letter) and it has now been 6 weeks since my interview. It's a different situation and what one would do to follow up after 1 week could very well differ from what one would do to follow up after 6 weeks.  I would appreciate any advice on how and when to follow up.